# Use event_data from map in Plotly R to render dataTable

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I need some help in using event_data in plotly r to render a dataTable instead of just showing the cwrevenumber and pointNumber.

```
    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv')    

    # light grey boundaries
     l <- list(color = toRGB("grey"), width = 0.5)

    # specify map projection/options
    g <- list(
      showframe = FALSE,
      showcoastlines = FALSE,
      projection = list(type = 'Mercator')
      )

      plot_ly(df, z = GDP..BILLIONS., text = COUNTRY, locations = CODE, type =       'choropleth', source = 'click', color = GDP..BILLIONS., colors = 'Blues', marker =     list(line = l),
        colorbar = list(tickprefix = '$', title = 'GDP Billions US$')) %>%
  layout(title = '2014 Global GDP<br>Source:<a href="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2195.html">CIA World Factbook</a>',
         geo = g)
    })


output$c_locate_info <- renderDataTable({
    event.data <- event_data(event='plotly_click', source = 'click') 

    if(is.null(event.data)==T) return('Select Regions for More Details')
    })
```

Comment: your example is not reproducible; we can't run your code.

Comment: @MLavoie, thanks for taking time to look at my issue. Basically what I am trying to know is, if we use the choropleth example in plotly r, can we click o the country and produce a table shows data from the plot using event_data.

Comment: the `event_data`  will have only information for the selected point, you need to retrieve your data and publish it if you want to see it as a table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the 'else' argument

```
output$c_locate_info <- renderDataTable({
event.data <- event_data(event='plotly_click', source = 'click') 

if(is.null(event.data)==T) return('Select Regions for More Details') else d
})
```